# Is showing all trees have $\rho$-valuation not enough to prove Ringel's conjecture about trees decomposing odd complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, conjectures

This might be a soft question, but I am trying to understand graceful labeling ($\beta$-valuation) and all the related stuff, and I have read Rosa's paper too.

I would like to know why most are focusing on showing that a tree always has $\beta$-valuation. Having that valuation implies having the $\rho$ one too, but are there trees having $\rho$-valuation that do not decompose their associated odd complete graph? I am trying to find papers on this but cannot find one. Maybe if we talk about graph in general, then maybe the answer is yes, but what happen if the graph is a tree?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So are you asking for a counterexample to Ringel's conjecture that all trees on $n$ edges decompose $K_{2n+1}$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think what I'm asking is whether showing all trees are graceful is necessary. I understand that $n$ edges graphs in general decompose $K_{2n+1}$ if they are graceful, including trees. I believed Rosa also showed that having $\rho$-valuation is enough to decompose $K_{2n+1}$. Hence I am asking, are there trees that have no such valuation? The conjecture is as u said, so maybe showing all trees have $\rho$-valuation is enough (except there is one that does not)?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I mean, $\rho$-valuation is an easier condition to achieve than $\beta$-valuation (gracefulness), right? So, instead of showing all trees have the latter latter, why don't we focus on the former?